# Calculate average value for a key with multiple values

Tags: python

I have the following nested array:

```
[["Diane", 20],["Bion",25],["Jack",30],["Bion",40],["Diane",50],["Jack",20]]
```

I want to calculate the average of each person. For example Diane's average = 35 (50+20)/2.

Comment: This is a nested list, neither an array nor a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, using a temporary `defaultdict` to store the total and number of entries for each person:

```
from collections import defaultdict

values = [["Diane", 20],["Bion",25],["Jack",30],["Bion",40],["Diane",50],["Jack",20]]

stats = defaultdict(lambda: {"num_entries": 0, "total": 0})

for name, value in values:
    stats[name]["num_entries"] += 1
    stats[name]["total"] += value

averages = {}

for name, stat in stats.items():
    averages[name] = stat["total"] / stat["num_entries"]

print(averages)
```

Output dict: `{'Diane': 35.0, 'Bion': 32.5, 'Jack': 25.0}`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
values = [["Diane", 20],["Bion",25],["Jack",30],["Bion",40],["Diane",50],["Jack",20]]
people = {}
for i in values: # type(i) -> list. i[0] are names, i[1] are values.
    if i[0] in people: # Check if it have the key.
        people[i[0]][0] += i[1] # Add value.
        people[i[0]][1] += 1 # Add 1 to entries count.
    else:
        people.update({i[0]:[i[1],1]}) # A new entry is made.
result = {i:people[i][0]/people[i][1] for i in people}
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'Diane': 30.0, 'Bion': 32.5, 'Jack': 25.0}
```

Basically I make a dictionary (people) with names like keys and lists (sum and number of entries) checking if the name is repeated (in the first for). Then, I make another dictionary with names like keys and the division of the contents of the list of the previous dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a nested list as per your requirement.

**Code:**

```
# Nested list of name and age
t = [["Diane", 20],["Bion",25],["Jack",30],["Bion",40],["Diane",50],["Jack",20]]

# Create a dictionary to combine all ages for a name
dict = {}
for k in t:
    if k[0] in dict:
        dict[k[0]].append(k[1])
    else:
        dict[k[0]] = [k[1]]

# Calculate average for each name
t2 = [] 
for key, value in dict.items():
    avg = sum(value) / float(len(value))
    t2.append([key, avg])

print(t2)
```

**Input:**

```
[["Diane", 20],["Bion",25],["Jack",30],["Bion",40],["Diane",50],["Jack",20]]
```

**Output:**

```
[['Diane', 35.0], ['Bion', 32.5], ['Jack', 25.0]]
```